# Deploy a jar in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

It is possible deploy a simple jar in tomcat and it run that???

A simple example,is just execute main and print a hello world :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not. You have to create a web app that includes your jar and a servlet (as a bare minimum).

Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: So,my jar just will start when something arrives to my servlet?

Comment: In your servlet you have to instantiate the class and call the method you want -- the class is in your jar.

Comment: And if never arrives a request? my jar will never start?

Comment: Then maybe you don't really need a servlet container. If you simply want to run the application locally you don't need Tomcat.

Comment: i Want to run locally,but want that it be remotly accessible

Comment: In that case you can write a simple web application. Start from the tutorial I've posted in my response, looks like you need some more knowledge on this matter

Answer (score 4):

No.

Tomcat is a web app container, you need to deploy a web app.