# Deploying a jar in tomcat like war file

Tags: tomcat, jar

I know we can deploy a war file. Can I export the Entire project as jar and deploy the jar file in tomcat ?

Comment: If your project is a web application, you will need to deploy a war.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648760/deploy-a-jar-in-tomcat).

You need to deploy with a war file - see [wikipedia for a description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)).

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated by other users, no, you can't. But moreover, think about what would happen if your project, in turn, had jar dependencies. How would you package them? That one of the roles of a war file.

I've seen different attempts of doing this, but all of them have serious problems, and also need a war. Things like re-packaging the project as one fat jar, or putting extra jars in tomcat/lib directory. That kind of approach has problems with class loading and app isolation from one another.

Don't go with that line of thinking, and I recommend you read about classloaders and how they play a role in particular in tomcat apps.

Hope that clarifies a little!

Answer (score 1):

You can't export **entire project** as jar file. Beyond compiled Java classes, your web application have images (jpg, gif, png, v.v..), JavaScript, css files... Variety of file types must deployed in WAR structure.

> **Packaging Web Modules**
>   
> A web module must be packaged into a WAR in
>   certain deployment scenarios and whenever you want to distribute the
>   web module. You package a web module into a WAR by executing the jar
>   command in a directory laid out in the format of a web module, by
>   using the Ant utility, or by using the IDE tool of your choice.

[image]

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html