# How do you package a GWT application in a fat JAR using maven?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jar

My GWT application is currently packaged into a war using maven, which is then deployed to tomcat. I'd want to change to packaging in a jar so it can be executed with java -jar, and have the application served from an embedded web server like Jetty. Similar to what happens when you run in dev mode, but I want it to happen from a single easily deployable fat/uber jar including html and GWT js files. I've only been able to find instructions for doing this for Jetty with spring, and haven't been able to adapt this for GWT. Something like [Jetty's example uber jar project](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar) is close, just needs to work with GWT as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the packaging of your maven project:

```
<project>
    ...
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

Please note that you [couldnt deploy a jar file in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648760/deploy-a-jar-in-tomcat).

Next I would make sure that the dependency `gwt-dev` has scope provided (since this dependency contains already an old version of jetty). After that you could add the jersey dependency and start an embedded server which serves your GWT-Appliccation (for example [see here](http://michelletilley.net/2010/03/27/serving-a-gwt-application-with-an-embedded-jetty-server.html)).

Comment: Thanks I've tried the link and it has helped me get closer, but I still haven't been able to have it all work with maven, and I'm after a solution where I can get a fat jar i.e. everything needed to run the webapp inside the jar including html, GWT js files etc without a separate war file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

[for more info](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't include everything I've asked i.e. GWT compiled js files in the jar, embedded web server etc.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the [example Jetty project](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar) and @mam10eks answer, I think I've managed to figure it out for a simple GWT app anyway:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.HelloJettyGwt</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloJettyGwt</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloJettyGwt</name>

<properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jetty-version>9.3.2.v20150730</jetty-version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>app.html</runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>com.example.HelloJettyGwt.app</module>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    src/main/webapp
                                </directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                                    <include>**/*.css</include>
                                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>

                            <resource>
                                <directory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/
                                </directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/app/**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                     <mainClass>com.example.HelloJettyGwt.ServerMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${jetty-version}</Implementation-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>rebuild-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/VERSION.txt</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE.txt</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <!-- exclude the MANIFEST.MF entries that will cause problems -->
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>javax.annotation:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>javax.servlet:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>javax.websocket:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.eclipse.jetty:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.ow2.asm:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-java</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireMavenVersion>
                                <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                            </requireMavenVersion>
                            <requireJavaVersion>
                                <version>[1.8,)</version>
                                <message>[ERROR] OLD JDK [${java.version}] in use.
                                    Jetty
                                    ${jetty-version} requires JDK 1.8 or newer</message>
                            </requireJavaVersion>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

main method:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    URL webRootLocation = this.getClass().getResource("/app.html");
    if (webRootLocation == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine webroot URL location");
    }

    URI webRootUri = URI.create(webRootLocation.toURI().toASCIIString().replaceFirst("/app.html$","/"));

    WebAppContext altHandler = new WebAppContext();
    altHandler.setResourceBase(Resource.newResource(webRootUri).toString());
    altHandler.setDescriptor(Resource.newResource(webRootUri).toString() + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
    altHandler.setContextPath("/");
    altHandler.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

    server.setHandler(altHandler);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Comment: Just found that while this works with mvn package && java -jar ... it doesnt work with super dev mode via mvn gwt:run